# Is it good practice to save date and time as one attributes?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing a database. I have one relation which have all the attributes for time log. And I have to make it foreign key in other relation which has items. But I am not sure whether to use date and time as separate attributes and make them a both primary key(composite key) or use a single dateTime attribute as a primary key.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to optimizing database queries its always good to have less joins between your different relationships and tables. Also if you save attribute with type as DATETIME it gives you more control of what you can do by performing single fetch of the column instead of fetching two columns and applying your application logic. Also it will help you overall keep the size of your metadata of database lower as well.

So in the light of above its highly recommended to keep both attributes  in single column with data type as DATETIME.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Shuja. Will it going to impact the performance of our database, if I use different attribute for date and time. Like you said, we have to perform join between the relation on 2 attributes. On the other hand we will performing join only one attribute dateTime. Also, what if we have to derive many attributes from this single attributes. In that case, will not there be an overhead cost for that?

Comment: Yes it will because data normalization and joining are 2 key aspects which impacts the performance of any database. I have always used single column with DATETIME attributes mostly I used it to stored created_at & updated_at columns at the same level of the database. Which helps me in not performing any extra queries or joins to evaluate any data based on the date or time. so Definitely it impacts the performance.

Comment: Thanks that helps!

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

For the attribute itself, use a single datetime column. It only makes sense to split if there is some semantics behind date and time taken separately.

Apart from that, it is rare to use a datetime column as a key. Usually you have a numeric (maybe surrogate) primary key and datetime is just an attribute. Maybe you don't expect two records occuring at exactly the same moment. Most often it turns out eventually to be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did not understand "semantics behind date and time". What do you mean by that? And also I would like to highlight that, I am using a sperate relation for time log. I have one to many relationship between timeLog and item relations, which means two items can happen at the same time. So this helps me remove redundancy in the item relation with all the data from timelog relations. Also this avoids introducing new key to the timeLog relation.

Comment: I meant: would your only question related to this attribute be when the event happened (datetime), i.e. is it atomic? Or maybe date and/or time alone has any business meaning and you need to query it / filter by it, etc. - so you would need to extract it from datetime?

Comment: Yes, i do need to use the datetime for derived attributes.